# Why is ORDER DESC LIMIT not working for a foreach inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, limit, records

Basically I have a `foreach` loop inside a `foreach` loop. The retrieved records all show up fine. But I want to `limit` those record results using `DESC LIMIT` in my second `foreach` loop. But it doesn't seem to work. I don't get any errors. It just returns ALL the records instead of the specified amount (5).

Here's my code.

```
$get_records = $db->prepare("SELECT users.*, referrals.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN referrals ON users.user_id = referrals.referred_user
WHERE referrals.referred_by = :ref_by");

$get_records->bindParam(':ref_by', $global_user_id);
$get_records->execute();
$result_records = $get_records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($result_records) > 0) {

  foreach($result_records as $row) {

    $ref_user_id = trim($row['user_id']); 
    $get_records2 = $db->prepare("SELECT users.*, referrals.* FROM users
    LEFT JOIN referrals ON users.user_id = referrals.referred_user
    WHERE referrals.referred_by = :ref_by ORDER BY referrals.referral_id DESC LIMIT 5");

    $get_records2->bindParam(':ref_by', $ref_user_id);
    $get_records2->execute();
    $result_records2 = $get_records2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result_records2) > 0) {

      foreach($result_records2 as $row) {

        $ref_username  = trim($row['username']);
        $ref_email     = trim($row['email']);
        $ref_joined    = trim($row['joined']);
        ?>
        <div class="table-row">
          <ul>
            <li class="th-1"><?php echo $ref_username; ?></li>
            <li class="th-2"><?php echo $ref_email; ?></li>
            <li class="th-3"><?php echo $ref_joined; ?></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not a good practice to execute mysql query within a loop. Please try to look for alternate options.

Comment: This could be made into a `JOIN` or a subquery. That would improve performance etc.